# Python while loop (range)

Tags: python, for-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WSl7.png)

I dont know what's went wrong in the 1st one when I type 5 it suppose to stop 
just like in the second one

thanks for your help.

Comment: Please dont add image.. Copy your question here..

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `str` returned by [input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to an `int` using

```
a = int(input("Enter number: "))
```